# Should a user authorize each time i need an access token?

Tags: authentication, facebook

In the [facebook authentication guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), i am suppose to:

1. Get the user to authorize my
   application, by redirecting them to
   authorize uri.
2. Get my access token
       from facebook by hitting the
       /outh/accesstoken uri.

Lets just say, that for whatever reason, this token is no longer valid. Do i need to perform step #1, or can i hit the /outh/accesstoken uri again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth 2.0 allows for "refresh tokens" which will do exactly what you want (hit the access token endpoint for a new token). However, Facebook does not support them.

If you want access after the user initially signed in, then you have three choices:

1/ Use the FB JavaScript library to request access in an iframe. It's not using OAuth (yet) but it will do it with minimal user disruption.

2/ Reirect the user to the OAuth endpoint again. If they have already authorized the requested scopes, then it will direct back immediately.

3/ Ask for the "offline_access" extended permission. This should only be used rarely.

Answer (score 0):

If the token is no longer valid, you have to get a new one.

Comment: Do i need to get the user to reauthorize my application (step one and two in the question), or do i just simply get a new token (step two only)